# Getting code=H12 status=503 error when deploying python flask chat app with socketIO to heroku

Tags: heroku, flask-socketio

[ChromeDevelopTools snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IHqZ.png)I have hosted my Slack clone app on https://flack-edx-cs50.herokuapp.com. It is an assignment from CS50 project2 from Harvard CS department.
The landing page has no issues. But once you login, it goes by default to AllUsers channel and then I get a bunch of errors on client due to socket.io.min.js. Server side application.py has no issues and heroku logs --tail showed build was successful.
I am getting this error:
heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc=Request timeout method=GET path=/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1605672542872-21&sid=2b46465af66e4d6c9f1bca49d31716e0 host=flack-edx-cs50.herokuapp.com request_id=95154d10-575c-47aa-b12a-46b4c8e432f8 fwd=67.180.168.171 dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30008ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
My code is public and located at https://github.com/rudyt/project2/tree/master/project2
The landing page is https://flack-edx-cs50.herokuapp.com
You can login with any Display Name and it is stored at local storage. No database is being used and everything is stored in server memory.
The network tab on the chrome debugger shows xhr request always pending. I am attaching the snapshot of the chrome debugger session. I see transport=polling in the error, and I hope that polling is supported in transport layer in heroku.

Comment: Not sure this is the problem, but you should add eventlet or gevent to your virtualenv so that the server can use WebSocket, right now it is working with long-polling, and these long requests are causing timeouts in Heroku.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. My Procfile has:       gunicorn -k geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker -w 1 application:app   Plz tell me what change I need to make to this line.

Comment: That command is correct. Then the next thing to check is that you are not blocking. If you block, then the server becomes unresponsive and Heroku will eventually timeout.

Comment: How do I check if it is blocking? When I do "heroku logs --tail" I am seeing" Received packet PING data None ,  Sending packet PONG data None" This is in chrome client. When I tried firefox, I get in the debugger: "Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://flack-edx-cs50.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=013ed7de0161406692d3894a5cde30d3." and also:"The connection to ws://flack-edx-cs50.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=013ed7de0161406692d3894a5cde30d3 was interrupted while the page was loading."

Comment: There is no generic test for blocking, you determine it by reviewing your code and making sure everything it does is compatible with greenlet concurrency.

Comment: I added transport:websocket in index.js as: var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port, {transports: ['websocket'] });
I dont see those errors any more. But I see internal server error 500 and the message in the heroku log " https://flack-edx-cs50.herokuapp.com is not an accepted origin." The app works fine in local host but not in heroku.

Comment: I found the comment on Nov18, 2019 on this link https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/1103 to be very helpful. The "is not an accepted origin" messages are gone now.